# Background fields in canonical formalism

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, quantum-electrodynamics

In quantum electrodynamics  problems  involving [background fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_field_method), most text books usually makes the following substitution

$$A^\mu \rightarrow A^{'\mu}= A_0^{\mu}+A_{c}^{\mu}$$

Where $A_{c}$ is classical field satisfying Maxwell equations.

In the path integral formalism this seems reasonable to do since,  $A_0^{\mu}$ and $A_{c}^{\mu}$ are $c$ numbers but in the canonical formalism   $A_0^{\mu}$ are an operator and $A_{c}^{\mu}$ a $c$ number.

Is this a reasonable thing  to do?

Comment: If $A$ is an operator and $z$ is a complex number, then $A+z$ should be interpreted as the operator $A+z1$, where $1$ is the identity operator.  The case with the operator $A^\mu$ is similar.  Conceptually, we can think of $A_0^\mu(x)$ as a different operator for each point $x$, and $A^\mu_c(x)$ as a different complex (well, real in this case) number for each point $x$, so $A_0^\mu(x)+A_c^\mu(x)$ means $A_0^\mu(x)+A_c^\mu(x)1$ where $1$ is the identity operator.  Is this what you were asking?

Comment: So if it as you say that means that the classical part $ A^\mu_c(x)$ can not create photon since it does not have a creation operator

Comment: Correct. For another perspective, consider a single harmonic oscillator, defining $a$ and $a^\dagger$ so that $[a,a^\dagger]=1$ as usual, and let $|0\rangle$ be annihilated by $a$.  For a c-number $a_c$, the state $|a_c\rangle =\exp(-a_c a^\dagger)|0\rangle$ is annihilated by $a+a_c$. The state $|a_c\rangle$ may be regarded as containing a "classical background oscillator" with complex amplitude $a_c$. Extending this perspective to an interacting QFT is challenging, maybe dubious, but maybe it has some pedagogical merit anyway.